# CSS Inheriting Width not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently attempting to create a browser-based Calendar which allows jobs or meetings, etc. to be overlayed on top, which will be retrieved dynamically with AJAX (or similar) and displayed to the end user.

Unfortunately, eiter my CSS is (very) rusty or this is just another oddity which I'm having difficulty getting my head around.

The basic idea is having a `<div>` which will be created for each meeting or job inside the correct `<td>` for the day/time in the calendar. However, I'm currently unable to get this div to inherit the width of the `<td>` so it doesn't overlap with other days.

The current CSS I'm using contains...

```
td {
    border-left: solid 1px gray;
    border-right: solid 1px gray;
    border-bottom: solid 1px lightgray;
    border-top: solid 1px lightgray;
    **width: 12.5%;**
    height: 10px;
    font-size: 0.1em;
}

div.job { 
       position: absolute; 
       background: #C83636; 
       background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.7); 
       font-size: 8px; 
       color: white; 
       margin-top: 3px; 
       width: inherit; 
       height: 10px; 
}
```

I will then create these divs using jquery as so:
     `$("#1-1").html("<div class='job'>Some test text</div>");`

As I understand it at the moment, this should mean that the created `<div>` inherits the width of the `<td>` it is enclosed in, and therefore fits into the cell nicely. However, this isn't happening in either Opera or Firefox when I'm testing it.
[What I see](http://i48.tinypic.com/2nvgdpw.png)

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: post your element with #1-1 html and css so that we could know how to solve

Comment: The table is created with PHP so as to have dynamic IDs for each `<td>`. However, it is essentially a very basic, pretty bland HTML table. The `<tr>`s have a class 'selectable' which does not have any style information, and the `<td>`s also have no other classes or IDs other than the '#1-1' or similar which is used only to identify their position.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but:

did you try setting the div's width to 100% instead of 'inherit' ?

Comment: That gives me [this](http://i49.tinypic.com/33n7xg8.png) . Is there any other info that I should post which could help?

Comment: ids shouldnt start with numbers try instead `id="row-1-1"`

Comment: @AbstractChaos Thanks, I'll make sure to change that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change position:absolute to position:relative for div.job class

Comment: also add fixed width for the tds instead of the percent value

Comment: Changing the position to relative (with fixed `<td>` width or not) does stop it from overlapping, but locks the div inside the td. I could very much use absolute positioning so the height can change over multiple cells - for instance, if a job or meeting goes on for longer than one set calendar 'period'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try "width:auto" on the job divs?

Possibly also set the divs to be "display:inline-block".

I think that what's happening just now is that your job divs are inheriting the 12.5% width so they are becoming 12.5% of the 12.5% (if that makes sense?).

Answer (score 0):

add display:inline block; to div.job

and here is little bit modification... use it as u like

```
td {
 border-left: solid 1px gray;
 border-right: solid 1px gray;
 border-bottom: solid 1px lightgray;
 border-top: solid 1px lightgray;
 width: 12.5%;
 height: 10px;
 font-size: 1.1em;
}
div.job { 
 background: #C83636;
 background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.7);
 font-size: 1.1em;
 color: white; width: 100%; height: 100%;display:inline-block }
```